# Sending Files via Bluetooth without Pairing

Tags: nautilus, bluetooth

How I can send and receive files via Bluetooth without Pairing the devices?
How can I add such send via Bluetooth option in Context Menu?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I personally have had problems with sending files anyway - even when paired. I don't think this is possible as otherswise you could easily spam someone's computer with junk fiels  or access files on someone's phone without permsssion. Why do you require this? It might help us help you if we know why you need it, as there may be an alternative.

Comment: Actually I want this process should be fast so I dont want that pairing, entering code in another device instead of that just right click and send file via bluetooth using context menu is a good option.

Comment: Surely once it is paired, you can just do that? You could connect it each time you log in. Unfortunataly that probably isn't possible becasuse of security problems.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without pairing the devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to send some files on some devices in hurry. I don't want that pairing each and every device for sending just 1 file. Instead of pairing I found a solution which may work for everyone who has his requirement.

- Search and install software **Bluetooth Manager** from Software Centre *(Search for item Blueman in Search Box)*
- Turn Bluetooth Switch on from **System Settings>>Bluetooth**
- Open **Bluetooth Manager** and click Search *(Top Left in App Window)* then select device Send File *(Top Right in App Window)*
- Select files and send

Comment: After installing it, I have 2 Bluetooth icons in the Application Indicator (panel, notification bar, or system tray).

Answer (score 1):

For sending files from a (mobile) device to ubuntu try 'gnome-user-share'.

https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-user-share/stable/gnome-user-share-getting-started.html.en

The settings can also be accessed via terminal: gnome-file-share-properties